# R - Mode imputation for NA and non-mode values with sorted dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, mode, imputation

I would like the use mode imputation on **weather** for a dataframe (stack_2) that is sorted by four columns  **schoolid**, **grade**, **date**, **time_of_day***.* In addition to imputation for the NA values, any weather value that is not the mode value should be inputed to the mode. If there are ties in the mode, then NA should be imputed for all values. I am not sure how to keep my data sorted and create the new variable **weather_mode_imputed.** An example of the imputed weather variable I am looking for is  presented in the stack_2 dataframe below as **weather_mode_imputed** with all possible situations shown.

I have never done mode imputation so not exactly sure what I need to do here, especially because my dataframe must be in the sorted order presented to input the weather variable, and has more than just imputation of NA values. Thanks!

```
dput(stack_2[1:15, ]) 

structure(list(schoolid = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), grade = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), date = c("5/21/19", 
"5/21/19", "5/21/19", "5/21/19", "5/21/19", "5/21/19", "5/21/19", 
"5/21/19", "5/21/19", "5/22/19", "5/22/19", "5/22/19", "5/22/19", 
"5/22/19", "5/22/19"), time_of_day = c("am", "am", "am", "am", 
"am", "pm", "pm", "pm", "pm", "am", "am", "am", "pm", "pm", "pm"
), weather = c("overcast", "overcast", "overcast", NA, "sunny", 
"overcast", "sunny", NA, "sunny", "overcast", "sunny", NA, "sunny", 
"sunny", "sunny"), weather_mode_imputed = c("overcast", "overcast", 
"overcast", "overcast", "overcast", "sunny", "sunny", "sunny", 
"sunny", NA, NA, NA, "sunny", "sunny", "sunny")), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach:

```
library(dplyr)

## helper function to return a vector's mode
get_mode <- \(xs) table(xs) |> sort(decreasing = TRUE) |> names() |> head(1)


df |>
    mutate(mode = get_mode(weather),
           ## coalesce(A, B) returns the first non-NA in columns A, B per row:
           weather_mode_imputed = coalesce(weather, mode)
           ) |>
    select(-mode)
```

Comment: still received errors with this code, when sunny was suppose to be the mode, overcast was for example. when grouped by **date** and **time_of_day**, all **weather_mode_imputed** values should be the mode of **weather** or NA if no mode.

Comment: Grouping before calculation returns the statistic (here: mode) per group. When this is not desired, `ungroup` before `get_mode`.